# Popup window with own text with JVectorMap

Tags: mapping, jvectormap

Is it possible to enable popup with not only country name but some additional text (for example, address, telephone) with JVectorMap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you bind handler for `onRegionLabelShow` event. The second parameter passed to the callback will be label jQuery element. See [documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api-v1/jvm-worldmap/). Example:

```
onRegionLabelShow: function(e, label, code){
  label.html(label.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
}
```